# App crashes after trying to run criminalintent

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I’m using my actual phone to run criminalintent. After declaring CrimeListActivity in the manisfest (Listing 9.13) and pressing run, the app crashes. “Unfortunately, criminalIntent has stopped”

Here is the error message.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.murach.criminalintent, PID: 13516
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.murach.criminalintent/com.murach.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support..v7.widget.RecyclerView
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3120)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3219)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6838)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support..v7.widget.RecyclerView
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                      at com.murach.criminalintent.CrimeListFragment.onCreateView(CrimeListFragment.java:25)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3248)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3200)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1250)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6573)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3083)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3219) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6838) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support..v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.murach.criminalintent-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:578)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                      at com.murach.criminalintent.CrimeListFragment.onCreateView(CrimeListFragment.java:25) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3248) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3200) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1250) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6573) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3083) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3219) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6838) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid name: android.support..v7.widget.RecyclerView
                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                            ... 32 more
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this your application, or someone else's?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: In your XML of the Fragment, the RecyclerView has an extra period `android.support..v7`